# Comparison of 2 values based on custom operator

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a library that parses query strings and evaluates the result for a given context. The query has the format `FIELD OPERATOR VALUE (AND|OR) ...`. The list of operators is constant, but the field's type can be customized (default primary types are supported right now - other types can be added).

To enable the user of the library to overwrite the behavior of the operators, there is a `FieldComparer` class that evaluates 2 values for a given operator. It uses the default comparer of the type, but can be extended to provide specialized behavior.

The `StringFieldComparer` is such a specialized comparer for fields of type string. It adds support for wildcards and regex.

**Operators**

```
public enum Operator
{
    Equals,
    LessThen,
    LessThenOrEquals,
    GraterThan,
    GraterThanOrEquals,
    NotEquals,
    Matches,
    NotMatches,
}
```

**FieldComparer**

```
public class FieldComparer<TFieldValue>
{
    protected FieldComparer()
    { }

    public virtual bool Compare(Operator op, TFieldValue left, TFieldValue right)
    {
        var comparer = Comparer<TFieldValue>.Default;
        switch (op)
        {
            case Operator.Equals:
                return comparer.Compare(left, right) == 0;
            case Operator.NotEquals:
                return comparer.Compare(left, right) != 0;
            case Operator.GraterThan:
                return comparer.Compare(left, right) < 0;
            case Operator.GraterThanOrEquals:
                return comparer.Compare(left, right) <= 0;
            case Operator.LessThen:
                return comparer.Compare(left, right) > 0;
            case Operator.LessThenOrEquals:
                return comparer.Compare(left, right) >= 0;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Operator '{op}' is not supported for type '{typeof(TFieldValue)}'");
        }
    }

    internal static FieldComparer<TFieldValue> Default { get; } = new FieldComparer<TFieldValue>();
}
```

**StringFieldComparer**

```
public class StringFieldComparer : FieldComparer<string>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Regex> myRegexes = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();

    public override bool Compare(Operator op, string left, string right)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
            case Operator.Matches:
            case Operator.NotMatches:
                var regex = GetRegex(left);
                var match = regex.IsMatch(right);
                return op == Operator.Matches ? match : !match;
            case Operator.Equals:
            case Operator.NotEquals:
                regex = GetWildcardRegex(left);
                match = regex.IsMatch(right);
                return op == Operator.Equals ? match : !match;
            default:
                return base.Compare(op, left, right);
        }
    }

    private Regex GetWildcardRegex(string left)
    {
        var pattern = Regex.Escape(left)
            .Replace(@"\*", ".*")
            .Replace(@"\?", ".");

        pattern = "^" + pattern + "$";

        return GetRegex(pattern);
    }

    private Regex GetRegex(string left)
    {
        Regex regex;
        if (!myRegexes.TryGetValue(left, out regex))
        {
            regex = new Regex(left, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            myRegexes.Add(left, regex);
        }
        return regex;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var comparerStr = new StringFieldComparer();
comparerStr.Compare(Operator.Equals, "Hello*", "Hello World"); // true
comparerStr.Compare(Operator.Matches, "He.lo.*", "Hello World"); // true

var comparerInt = FieldComparer<int>.Default;
comparerInt.Compare(Operator.Equals, 1, 1); // true
comparerInt.Compare(Operator.LessThan, 1, 4); // false
```

---

I am not really happy with the method `StringFieldComparer.Compare` because the `op` will be checked twice for `Equals`/`NotEquals` and `Match`/`NotMatch`. Is there a way to realize it with only one check without creating the regex unnecessarily?

As always, any feedback is welcome! :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with that regx?

Comment: @Paparazzi: which regex? ;P

Comment: @t3chb0t: usage section added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public class FieldComparer<TFieldValue>
> {
>   protected FieldComparer()
>   { }
> }
> ```

The *right* way to prevent a type from being created and allowing only derived types to do it is... to use an `abstract` class. By making the `FieldComparer` `abstract` you won't need to *hide* the default constructor.

An example implementation could look like this where you have a `private class DefaultFieldComparer` that *implements* the `FieldComparer`:

```
public abstract class FieldComparer<TFieldValue>
{
    ..

    internal static FieldComparer<TFieldValue> Default { get; } = new DefaultFieldComparer();

    private class DefaultFieldComparer : FieldComparer<TFieldValue> { }
}
```

I find this is a cleaner solution becasue it informs me that the `FieldComparer` is a base class and intended be subclassed becasue on its own it has no use but if it has, then it should be instantiable.

---

> ```
> private readonly Dictionary<string, Regex> myRegexes = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();
>
> private Regex GetRegex(string left)
> {
>   Regex regex;
>   if (!myRegexes.TryGetValue(left, out regex))
>   {
>       regex = new Regex(left, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
>       myRegexes.Add(left, regex);
>   }
>   return regex;
> }
> ```

I'm not sure whether it's really necessary to use a dictionary for the regexes. In most cases the static [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) is sufficient and it already does the caching thing:

> The static IsMatch(String, String) method is equivalent to constructing a Regex object with the regular expression pattern specified by pattern and calling the IsMatch(String) instance method. **This regular expression pattern is cached for rapid retrieval by the regular expression engine.**

Comment: 1) That's true. Actually I would prefer an abstract class, but the generic type `FieldComparer<TFieldValue>` will be created when accessing the static `Default` property. If it becomes abstract it has to be subclassed by another internal class... Would you prefer that solution?

Comment: @JanDotNet I've added an example and an explanation for my reasoning.

Comment: 2) I did a quick test and the compiled version is ~6-7 times faster than `Regex.IsMatch`. You are right, in most cases it shouldn't matter,  but the comparer may be used very often. Therefore I will keep the caching logic ;)

Comment: @JanDotNet if you have numbers then it's fine (and good to know) - you cannot argue with measurements ;-)

Comment: 2) Also interesting: Providing option `RegexOptions.Compiled` for static method Regex.IsMatch is not a good idea... it slows down the regex evaluation by factor ~100-200 (compared with the regex instance with option `RegexOptions.Compiled` set)

Comment: @JanDotNet it's a pity that the documentation does not clearly state such behaviour. I find they should not cache any pattern so that you can implement your own caching or there should be an option for it.

Comment: _This regular expression pattern is cached for rapid retrieval by the regular expression engine._. Probably the pattern is cached so that repeated execution of the same pattern is faster... but **caching the pattern** may be different to **creating a compiled regex**.

Comment: I think I'll go with the abstract class. Look better to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

remove some repeated code

```
var comparer = Comparer<TFieldValue>.Default;
int comp = comparer.Compare(left, right);
switch (op)
{
    case Operator.Equals:
        return comp == 0;
    case Operator.NotEquals:
        return comp != 0;
```

Comment: Such obviously... thx!